# How to filter the JSON on boolean value

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

```json
{
  "L1": [
    {
      "f1": "446",
      "f2": true,
      "f3": true
    },
    {
      "f1": "191",
      "f2": true,
      "f3": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to filter where f2 is true and f3 is true in PostgreSQL.

Comment: Should that condition apply to **all** elements of the array or to at least one? i.e. if in the above array you have a third element with `f1 = false` should the row be returned?

Comment: It should apply to all. f1 is not false btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON path query to get all elements where both keys are true and then compare that to the total length of the array:

```
select ...
from the_table
where jsonb_array_length(the_column -> 'L1') = jsonb_array_length(jsonb_path_query_array(the_column, '$.L1[*] ? (@.f2 == true && @.f3 == true)'))
```

Comment: it is not working as I want to filter based on true/false value of f2 and f3.

Comment: Well, your question said: "*I want to filter where f2 is true and f3 is true" which is exactly what my answer does: https://dbfiddle.uk/-WZ3AFY8  If that is not what you want, you need to rephrase your question or add better sample data.